# Using python array's column as boolean to change another column's values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I am farily new to python, so that may be why I haven't been able to search properly in this site for an answer to my problem, in case someone know about it already.

I am reading several data files consisting in six columns: XYZ coordinates and 3-vector components around a sphere. I am using the X and Z coordinates to find the angle location of my vectors, and using the angle results as a new column to my array, as a fourth column. So, I have a 7 column array.

The angles are calculated with np.arctan and they get (-) or (+) sign depending on the quadrant the XZ coordinates are located.

Now, I want to make all the angles around the upper half of the sphere (Z positive) positive and spanning from 0º to 180º. On the other hand, I want my angles around the lower half to be negative, and going from 0º to -180º.

The operations to change sign and apply the 0º-180º range are easy to implement. But, I want to use the third column of my array (Z coordinates) as the boolean to decide how to change the angles (fourth column of the array). I have read quite a lot of info about slicing arrays, or modifying columns/rows based on arbitrary boolean conditions applied to the same columns/rows.

I am trying to avoid combining for-loops and if-statements, and learn how to use the power of the python :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `np.arctan2(a, b)` in place of `np.arctan(a/b)`. i think this might solve your entire problem

Comment: It might help if you could provide sample data, and what you might expect the output to be. If you have some code, even better!

Comment: Thank you Eric, that has fixed it! I guess I need to re-read about arctan2 more carefully.

Comment: Wayne, I didn't think it was necessary to post a chunck of my data. Apologies for that, next time I will be mroe thorough in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.where(cond, if_true, if_false)` solves the problem you *think you have*:

```
fixed_angle = np.where(z > 0, angle, -angle)
```

The problem you *actually have* is that you are not using [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), or as it's spelt in numpy, `np.arctan2`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Eric!

Comment: Double thanks! I've just found out it also converts my angle range to the one desired.
Where can I add stars to your comment???